# mysql ordering exception

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

I have a MySQL database and a have a funny question.

I need to order the results of a query by a field which has entries of 1,2,3 or 4, ordered descending but with 4 at the end.

So I wish to have the results in the following order

3's
2's
1's
4's

Is this possible at all?

I know I can do order the result array in php but unfortunately I need to do this in an sql statement.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If the field is an `int`,

```
ORDER BY (fieldname = 4) DESC, fieldname DESC
```

should do the trick.

Comment: Hey Pekka, thanks for that, (fieldname = 3) did the job, can you edit you post I tried but couldn't, Thank very much .k

Comment: @Keet thanks, I indeed had it the wrong way round. It should be correct now!

Answer (score 2):

Here is another cool way

```
ORDER BY MOD(fieldname,4) DESC,fieldname
```

If the result is a CHAR(1) then

```
ORDER BY LOCATE(fieldname,'3214'),fieldname
```

Answer (score 1):

add this to the order

`ORDER BY 
  CASE field_name WHEN 4 THEN 1 
  ELSE 2
  END`

this will return the result of the query order using the value of the field